# Why is part of the output "Null"?

Tags: matrix, warning-messages, output

Whenever I execute the code, portions of the output are null. How can I fix this? I am not sure the extent to which the result is invalid because I am not entirely familiar with the null output, though I have read the documentation. The point in which this problem arises is labeled in the following code:

```
 omega[t_, t0_, T_] = Exp[(-(t - t0)^2)/T^2];
    omegap[t_, t0p_, Tp_] = Exp[-((t - t0p)^2)/Tp^2];
    eff[t_, t0p_, 
       Tp_] = ((omega[t, t0, T])^2 - (omegap[t, t0p, 
           Tp])^2)/(2 \[CapitalDelta]);
    eff[t_, t0p_, 
       Tp_] = (omegap[t, t0p, Tp]*omega[t, t0, T])/(\[CapitalDelta]);
    ReducedHam = ({
        {\[CapitalDelta]eff[t, t0p, Tp], \[CapitalOmega]eff[t, t0p, Tp]*
          Exp[Sqrt[-1]*\[CurlyPhi]]},
        {\[CapitalOmega]eff[t, t0p, Tp]*
          Exp[-Sqrt[-1]*\[CurlyPhi]], -\[CapitalDelta]eff[t, t0p, Tp]}
       });
    Print[MatrixForm[ReducedHam]]
    \[Theta][t_, t0p_, Tp_] = ArcTan[omegap[t, t0p, Tp]/omega[t, t0, T]];
    \[Lambda]1 = ({
        {Cos[\[Theta]]},
        {-Sin[\[Theta]]*Exp[-Sqrt[-1]*\[CurlyPhi]]}
       });
    \[Lambda]2 = ({
        {Sin[\[Theta]]*Exp[Sqrt[-1]*\[CurlyPhi]]},
        {Cos[\[Theta]]}
       });
    Print[MatrixForm[\[Lambda]1]]
    Print[MatrixForm[\[Lambda]2]]
    Mat1 = (D[\[Lambda]1, \[Theta]]).(Transpose[\[Lambda]1]);
    Print[Mat1]
    V1 = Transpose[\[Lambda]1].D[\[Lambda]1, \[Theta]];
    V2 = \[Lambda]1.Transpose[\[Lambda]1];
    Print[MatrixForm[V2]]
    Mat2 = V1[[1, 1]] V2;
    Print[Mat2]
    Dimensions[Mat2];
    Mat12 = Mat1 - Mat2;
    Print[MatrixForm[Mat12]]
    Mat3 = Print[
       MatrixForm[D[\[Lambda]2, \[Theta]].Transpose[\[Lambda]2]]];
    V3 = Transpose[\[Lambda]2].D[\[Lambda]2, \[Theta]];
    V4 = \[Lambda]2.Transpose[\[Lambda]2];
    Print[MatrixForm[V4]]
    Mat4 = V3[[1, 1]] V4;
    Print[MatrixForm[Mat4]]
    Mat34 = Mat3 - Mat4;
    CDTerm = Mat12 + Mat34 ;
    Print[MatrixForm[Simplify[CDTerm]]]
    (*this is where null arises*)
    TotalHam = ReducedHam + CDTerm;
    Print[MatrixForm[Simplify[TotalHam]]]
    Dimensions[ReducedHam]
    Dimensions[CDTerm]
    \[CapitalOmega]a[t_, t0p_, 
      Tp_] = (2 (((D[omega[t, t0, T], t])*(omegap[t, t0p, Tp])) - ((omega[
              t, t0, T]) (D[omegap[t, t0, T], t]))))/((omegap[t, t0, 
          T])^2 + (omega[t, t0, T]^2))
    \[Gamma][t_, t0_, T_, \[CurlyPhi]_] = 
      ArcTan[(\[CapitalOmega]a[t, t0p, Tp])/(\[CapitalOmega]eff[t, t0p, 
           Tp])] + \[CurlyPhi];
    f1[t_, t0_, 
      T_, \[CurlyPhi]_] = (Exp[(Sqrt[-1]*\[Gamma][t, t0, 
           T, \[CurlyPhi]])]/2)
    f2[t_, t0_, T_, \[CurlyPhi]_] = 
     Exp[(Sqrt[-1]*\[Gamma][t, t0, T, \[CurlyPhi]])/2]
    U = ({
       {f1[t, t0, T, \[CurlyPhi]], 0},
       {0, f2[t, t0, T, \[CurlyPhi]]}
      })
    Mat5 = ConjugateTranspose[U].TotalHam.U;
    Print[MatrixForm[Mat5]]
    Mat6 = ConjugateTranspose[U].(D[U, t]);
    Print[MatrixForm[Mat6]]
    HModified = Mat5 - Mat6;
    Print[MatrixForm[Simplify[HModified]]]
```

Comment: `Mat3` is `Null`, since `Print[…]` always returns `Null`. You might be interested in [`Echo`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Echo.html), which always returns its argument. For the next time, try to look at the different values of the expression that contains `Null` - this way, you can easily trace the error back to its origin (the `Mat3=Print[…]` line in this case). For this, `Echo` is your friend, as you can just put it in front of anything you want to look at

Answer (score 2):

Just leave out the `Print` functions, and remember not to throw away the results with `;`. Example:

```
m1 = IdentityMatrix[3];
MatrixForm[m1]
m2 = 3 m1;
MatrixForm[m2]
```

[image]
Most experienced *Mathematica* users rarely use `Print`. To show results, just evaluate them.

A more compact, functional form is:

```
MatrixForm[m1 = IdentityMatrix[3]]
MatrixForm[m2 = 3 m1]
```

Same output as above.